# Android: ClickableSpan on the last word of TextView works not properly

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I use this excellent hashtag lib: https://github.com/danylovolokh/HashTagHelper

However, there is a bad behavior in this case:

> hello it's my last #word

If the last ClickableSpan matchs with the last word in the TextView, then if I don't click in this hashtag but in the TextView (at the end), the click on this hastag is done!

Here you are with this screenshot: the blue rectangle is my TextView; the red cross is a click inside this TextView but not on my last hashtag #word.

[image]

In this library, there is this method to specify an hashtag. In my example,
nextNotLetterDigitCharIndex variable value is 23 (this value is correct).

```
if (nextNotLetterDigitCharIndex != -1) {

            Spannable s = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();

            CharacterStyle span;

            if (mOnHashTagClickListener != null) {
                span = new ClickableForegroundColorSpan(mHashTagWordColor, this);
            } else {
                // no need for clickable span because it is messing with selection when click
                span = new ForegroundColorSpan(mHashTagWordColor);
            }

            s.setSpan(span, startIndex, nextNotLetterDigitCharIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
```

Ps : in nominal mode, this TextView contains several lines.

Comment: I think you should open an issue to HashTagHelper proj
(https://github.com/danylovolokh/HashTagHelper/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue. My solution is just adding a space char after the last clickableSpan.